# Passing Argv to javascript form scala with JavaScript Engine and Trireme

Tags: javascript, node.js, scala, playframework, typesafe

I'm trying some server-side rendering with scala, play framework and react.js

At the moment I can render js from scala using js-engine (https://github.com/typesafehub/js-engine) but I want to give the js code some arguments (so I can do routing). This is what I have:

```
def app(route: String) = serverSideWithJsEngine(Trireme.props(), route)

private def serverSideWithJsEngine(jsEngine: Props, route: String) = Action.async { request =>
   import akka.pattern.ask

   val serverside=Play.getFile("target/web/public/main/serverSide.js")
   implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)
   val engine = Akka.system.actorOf(jsEngine, s"engine-${request.id}")

   for {
     result <- (engine ? Engine.ExecuteJs(
     source = new File(serverside.toURI),
     args = List(route),
     timeout = timeout.duration
     )).mapTo[JsExecutionResult]
  } yield {
     Ok(views.html.app(Html(new String( result.output.toArray, "UTF-8")
  )))
  }
}
```

This code renders the app but in theory, args = List(route) should give me "route" in the process.argv array from JS but I get an empty array.

Maybe is a bug from js-engine not passing args?? I don't understand why this code doesn't work...

Thanks!